# hmac message encryption but using our own key

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, hmac

```
try { // Generate a key for the HMAC-MD5 keyed-hashing algorithm
     KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("HmacMD5");
     SecretKey key = keyGen.generateKey(); 
    // Generate a key for the HMAC-SHA1 keyed-hashing algorithm 
keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("HmacSHA1"); 
        key = keyGen.generateKey(); } 
        catch (java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException e) { }
```

Above code would give us keys to digest a message using HMAC. Now i wanted to implement a HMAC logic in java where the key would be given by user.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct a `KeySpec` using the provided user key (either a `SecretKeySpec` if it's a byte array, or a `PBEKeySpec` if it's a password), then use a `SecretKeyFactory` to turn that into a `SecretKey`.